# How to fetch data from weather rest api using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Stackoverflow community can you people help me how I can extract data from that weather rest api using JavaScript. I can not able to fetch weather condition and data and time using this api.

```
{
    info: {
        _postman_id: "3683bf65-703d-2798-6901-c97ed650c68f",
            name: "IOT",
                schema: "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.0.0/collection.json"
    },
    item: [
        {
            name: "Find",
            id: "df046832-3c4d-950c-ae9f-dae36af7ebc7",
            request: {
                method: "POST",
                header: [
                    {
                        key: "Content-Type",
                        value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                ],
                body: {
                    mode: "urlencoded",
                    urlencoded: [
                        {
                            key: "table",
                            value: "data",
                            type: "text"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "search",
                            value: "{"device":"24: 6f: 28: 7a: 87: c2","date":{"$gt":"time(2021 - 02 - 21T13: 10: 48.593Z)","$lt":"time(2021 - 02 - 21T14: 10: 48.593Z)"}}",
                            type: "text"
                        },
                        {
                            key: "",
                            value: "{"device":"24: 6f: 28: 7a: 87: c2","date":{"$lt":"time(Sun Feb 21 2021 16: 59: 53 GMT + 0300(Arabian Standard Time))"}}",
                            type: "text"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                url: "http://185.247.117.33/DB/Find"
            },
            response: []
        }
    ]
}
```

my code for fetching data from that api

```
fetch('https://www.postman.com/collections/3175ec392efd66dc9a50')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    
  console.log(data.item[0].request.body.urlencoded[1].value)
  console.log(data.item[0].request.body.urlencoded[2].value) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

plz anyone help me how i can fetch data in array time and wheather conditions.

Comment: Hi, can you add in your post the URL of your request and a complete code that you use for try it !

Comment: What is the above code for , Is it a response or sample? Please label your code. And, add your complete code here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse results before use it.

```
fetch('https://www.postman.com/collections/3175ec392efd66dc9a50')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    
  let value1 = JSON.parse(data.item[0].request.body.urlencoded[1].value)
  let value2 = JSON.parse(data.item[0].request.body.urlencoded[2].value);
   console.log ( value1.date, value2.date);
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Answer (score 0):

The data inside `urlencoded` is JSON formatted, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to a object;

```js
fetch('https://www.postman.com/collections/3175ec392efd66dc9a50')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

    const value = data.item[0].request.body.urlencoded[1].value;
    const json  = JSON.parse(value);
    
    console.log(json.device);
    console.log(json.date['$gt']);
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))

// Output:
// 24:6f:28:7a:87:c2
// time(2021-02-21T13:10:48.593Z)
```

Comment: Thanks sir but how can we fetch weather conditions.If you can help me then i will very thank full of you
Link:https://www.postman.com/collections/3175ec392efd66dc9a50